# Tests failed after installing leptonica 1.73 on Xunbuntu 15.10

Tags: xubuntu

I am trying to install leptonica in order to use and train tesseract-ocr 3.04.

When entering the following commands in the leptonica-1.73 folder:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
make check
```

I get the following test fails:

```
Making check in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/andrea/Downloads/leptonica-1.73/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'check'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/andrea/Downloads/leptonica-1.73/src'
Making check in prog
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/andrea/Downloads/leptonica-1.73/prog'
make  alphaops_reg alphaxform_reg bilateral2_reg binarize_reg blackwhite_reg blend3_reg blend4_reg colorcontent_reg coloring_reg colorize_reg colormask_reg colorquant_reg colorspace_reg compare_reg convolve_reg dewarp_reg dna_reg dwamorph1_reg enhance_reg findcorners_reg findpattern_reg fpix1_reg fpix2_reg genfonts_reg graymorph2_reg hardlight_reg insert_reg ioformats_reg jpegio_reg kernel_reg label_reg maze_reg multitype_reg nearline_reg newspaper_reg overlap_reg paint_reg paintmask_reg pdfseg_reg pixa2_reg pixserial_reg pngio_reg pnmio_reg projection_reg psio_reg psioseg_reg pta_reg rankbin_reg rankhisto_reg rasteropip_reg rotate1_reg rotate2_reg rotateorth_reg scale_reg seedspread_reg selio_reg shear1_reg shear2_reg skew_reg splitcomp_reg subpixel_reg texturefill_reg     threshnorm_reg translate_reg warper_reg writetext_reg xformbox_reg   
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/andrea/Downloads/leptonica-1.73/prog'
make[2]: 'alphaops_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'alphaxform_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'bilateral2_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'binarize_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'blackwhite_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'blend3_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'blend4_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'colorcontent_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'coloring_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'colorize_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'colormask_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'colorquant_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'colorspace_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'compare_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'convolve_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'dewarp_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'dna_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'dwamorph1_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'enhance_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'findcorners_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'findpattern_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'fpix1_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'fpix2_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'genfonts_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'graymorph2_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'hardlight_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'insert_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'ioformats_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'jpegio_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'kernel_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'label_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'maze_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'multitype_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'nearline_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'newspaper_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'overlap_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'paint_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'paintmask_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'pdfseg_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'pixa2_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'pixserial_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'pngio_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'pnmio_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'projection_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'psio_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'psioseg_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'pta_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'rankbin_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'rankhisto_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'rasteropip_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'rotate1_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'rotate2_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'rotateorth_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'scale_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'seedspread_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'selio_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'shear1_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'shear2_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'skew_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'splitcomp_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'subpixel_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'texturefill_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'threshnorm_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'translate_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'warper_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'writetext_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: 'xformbox_reg' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/andrea/Downloads/leptonica-1.73/prog'
make  check-TESTS
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/andrea/Downloads/leptonica-1.73/prog'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/andrea/Downloads/leptonica-1.73/prog'
FAIL: alphaops_reg
PASS: alphaxform_reg
PASS: bilateral2_reg
PASS: binarize_reg
PASS: blackwhite_reg
FAIL: blend3_reg
FAIL: blend4_reg
PASS: colorcontent_reg
PASS: coloring_reg
PASS: colorize_reg
SKIP: colormask_reg
PASS: colorquant_reg
SKIP: colorspace_reg
FAIL: compare_reg
FAIL: convolve_reg
PASS: dewarp_reg
SKIP: dna_reg
FAIL: dwamorph1_reg
SKIP: enhance_reg
FAIL: findcorners_reg
PASS: findpattern_reg
SKIP: fpix1_reg
PASS: fpix2_reg
FAIL: genfonts_reg
PASS: graymorph2_reg
PASS: hardlight_reg
FAIL: insert_reg
PASS: ioformats_reg
PASS: jpegio_reg
SKIP: kernel_reg
FAIL: label_reg
PASS: maze_reg
PASS: multitype_reg
SKIP: nearline_reg
FAIL: newspaper_reg
PASS: overlap_reg
FAIL: paint_reg
FAIL: paintmask_reg
FAIL: pdfseg_reg
FAIL: pixa2_reg
FAIL: pixserial_reg
FAIL: pngio_reg
FAIL: pnmio_reg
SKIP: projection_reg
FAIL: psio_reg
FAIL: psioseg_reg
FAIL: pta_reg
SKIP: rankbin_reg
SKIP: rankhisto_reg
PASS: rasteropip_reg
PASS: rotate1_reg
PASS: rotate2_reg
PASS: rotateorth_reg
FAIL: scale_reg
PASS: seedspread_reg
PASS: selio_reg
PASS: shear1_reg
PASS: shear2_reg
FAIL: skew_reg
PASS: splitcomp_reg
PASS: subpixel_reg
FAIL: texturefill_reg
PASS: threshnorm_reg
PASS: translate_reg
FAIL: warper_reg
PASS: writetext_reg
FAIL: xformbox_reg
=======================
26 of 57 tests failed
(10 tests were not run)
See prog/test-suite.log
=======================
```

Also, from a found question on the subject, entering

```
$ grep '^#define HAVE_' config.log
```

gives me the following output

```
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
#define HAVE_LIBZ 1
#define HAVE_LIBPNG 1
#define HAVE_LIBJPEG 1
#define HAVE_FMEMOPEN 1
```

I am new on Xubuntu and with leptonica, thanks for your help!